# Shortcode Attributes - post__not_in array

Tags: shortcode

I'm trying to put together a shortcode that let's  the user loop posts but exclude specific ones by id.

```
 $atts = array_change_key_case((array)$atts, CASE_LOWER);

    // override default attributes with user attributes
    $custom_atts = shortcode_atts([
                                     'link' => 'off',
                                     'hide' => '',
                                     'only' => '',
                                     'reverse' => '',
                                 ], $atts, $tag);

    $args = array(
        'cat' => 113,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_parent'     => $current_id,
            'post__not_in'    => array($custom_atts['hide'])

    );


    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then the shortcode would look like:

```
[customposts hide="7043,7128"]
```

But for whatever reason it's only hiding the first post listed in the attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With this part:

```
'post__not_in' => array($custom_atts['hide'])
```

you're actually running:

```
'post__not_in' => array( "7043,7128" )
```

with `[customposts hide="7043,7128"]`.

Note that `post__not_in` expects an array of numbers, not an array with a single CSV element.

Have a look at e.g. [wp_parse_id_list()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_id_list/) and don't forget to validate the input, to e.g. avoid empty input or a one with non integers.

PS: This can potentially be eat up your resources for large number of posts:

```
'posts_per_page' => '-1'
```

Consider adding a limit there instead.